# sudo apt-get update command not performing all the task in Ubuntu 16.04 and finishes in 4-5 lines

Tags: apt, updates

I am getting this error while running `sudo apt-get update` please suggest what to do. Is this occurring due to the operation `sudo apt-get remove --purge runit`. This after the operation I performed in the question [Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code in16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774086/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-in16-04lts)

[image]

Comment: output of sudo apt-get update is shown in Image

Answer (score 1):

Command `apt update` only updates the package lists. Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

to upgrade the actual packages. People often combine the two as:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have couple `repository's` got in the way remove it from here

[image: repository]

and then click on `close` and run `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`